# $11$-adic expansion of 1/10

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am working through Koblitz's book on $p$-adic numbers and in one of the exercises, he asks us to find the $11$-adic expansion of $\frac{1}{10}$. My idea was to use the fact that $$\frac{1}{10}=(-1)\frac{1}{1-11^1}=(-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty 11^n.$$

But now I'm confused. The series on the right looks exactly like a multiplicative inverse (it's $\dots 1111_{11}$). I know $(-1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (p-1)p^n$ for all $p$-adics but then it seems to me that the multiplication returns $-1$. What am I missing?

Comment: You mean $11^n$ not $10^n$ in the sum

Comment: @user10354138 You're absolutely right, my bad!

Comment: This looks like the  **non-unique** property of decimal representation of certain numbers, like $0.9999....=1.$

Comment: What multiplication are you talking  about? I don't see any contradiction, what exactly is bothering you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown that $-\frac{1}{10} = \ldots\!111_{11}$. Which is true, no problems here! It sounds like you are worried that $(-1)\times \ldots\!111_{11} = \ldots\!(10)(10)(10)_{11} \times \ldots\!111_{11}$ gives $-1$? Well, it doesn't... maybe you are multiplying pointwise (term by term) by mistake?

Instead of working out the result of $\ldots\!(10)(10)(10)_{11} \times \ldots\!111_{11}$, it's easier to do something like:
$$
-\frac{9}{10} = 9\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{10}\right) = \ldots\!999_{11}
$$
$$
\implies \frac{1}{10} = -\frac{9}{10} + 1 = \ldots\!999(10)_{11}
$$
It should also be possible to verify directly that $\ldots\!(10)(10)(10)_{11} \times \ldots\!111_{11} = \ldots\!999(10)_{11}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was under the impression that $p$-adic multiplication works like long multiplication (with carries, etc). Did I get this wrong? This is what Koblitz explicitly states in the book. I quote: "The only difference is that "carrying", [...], "long multiplication" go from left to right [...]."

Comment: It does. We can start: $10\cdot 1=(10)_{11}$, so the last digit is $(10)$. $10\cdot1+10\cdot1=19_{11}$, so next digit is $9$ and we carry the $1$. $1 + 10\cdot1+10\cdot1+10\cdot1=29_{11}$, so next digit is $9$ and we carry the $2$. And so on

Comment: Oh, and carrying goes to the left as usual when we use the notation $\ldots \!a_2a_1a_0$. Another notation would write the same number as $a_0.\!a_1a_2\!\ldots$, and then carrying would go to the right.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see! This is different because of the carrying. Okay, I get it now. Thank you very much!